# Google play test purchase

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I recently released a mobile app and everything was working great...at first. The app is free with an option to subscribe yearly. Unfortunately, when the user try's to subscribe, the pay dialog order says it's a test order and expires in 30 minutes. Cant figure out why this is happening and I'm losing money and business. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is in full production mode.

[image: Order Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some head scratching I realized that the test orders were every thirty minutes and it was happening on only my device. So others learn from my mistake, be sure to remove all of your testers before going live.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have left some testing code in your app by mistake. Maybe the subscription is using a test id? Without some more of your purchase code in your question it is going to be hard to help.

The help pages on [testing Google Play billing payments are here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing).

It sounds like you have added the users to your testers list.